# user.emailVerified does not change to 'true' in response to sendEmailVerification link (firebase auth)

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

someone please help, what am I missing? I send verification email (using firebase sendEmailVerification) succesfully and when I click on the link on the email it does not work, so i end up copying the link and paste in on the browser and hit enter. that way I'm able to get back to my web app and the continue URL does work. This just does not change user.emaiVerified to true.

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
if(user) {
    user.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings)
        .then( () => {
            console.log("UnpSignUpForm: Verification email sent SUCCESSFULLY");
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log('UnpSignUpForm: Verification email sending error: ', error)
        });  
    } else {
        console.log('no user')
}
```

I tried using user.reload() in onAuthStateChanged (see below) but I still cannot get user.emailVerified changed to "true".

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
    // console.log('onAuthStateChanged user', user)

    if (user) {
        console.log('onAuthStateChanged: user is signed IN')
        console.log('onAuthStateChanged user', user)

        user.reload()
        console.log(`user ${user.email} reloaded`)

        // User is signed in.
        if(user.emailVerified) {
            console.log('onAuthStateChanged:email Verified', user.emailVerified)

        } else {
            console.log('onAuthStateChanged:email NOT Verified', user.emailVerified)     
        }

    } else {
        console.log('onAuthStateChanged: onAuthStateChanged: user is signed OUT')
   }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

After the user clicks the link, `emailVerified` is not automatically updated. It will be updated when the user is reloaded, eg. `user.reload()`.

In addition, the `email_verified` field in the token claims will be either updated when the token is naturally refreshed after expiration or if you force token refresh after the user email is verified, eg. `user.getIdToken(true)`.

Comment: tnx for your respponse. I tried `user.getIdToken(true)`, it still does not work. Perhaps if I can find a link that details how firebase/auth work under the hood. May be that can help.

Comment: `user.getIdToken(true)` only updates the `email_verified` claim inside the token. `user.emailVerified` is only updated on user reload.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you found out what might have been the problem. I just figured it out. I'm using React.

When you got the email to verify your password, you will have noticed the link looked something like this:

https://yourappname.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=p-s8GYqQN9AxuwyVFc7FDe3R3d4O-SIf_6_H4vRMiZtcAAAF3RIT1CA&apiKey=llllllllRLl2LsK842iT9797yHciGBtTuuVVKzs&lang=en

If you inspect the URL, you'll notice 4 parameters:

1. **mode**
2. **oobCode**
3. **apiKey**
4. **lang**

When you click on the link, you'll be forwarded to the url you set in your firebase console.

[image: You can find it in Authentication > Templates]

When you access the url in the verification email, you'll need to find a way to parse the query parameters. There's a nice npm package for this called [query string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) which does all the dirty work for you. It also has easy-to-read documentation and I found it easy to implement on React.

Once I parsed the oobCode from the url parameters, I used it as an argument for the following method:

```
firebase.auth().applyActionCode(<add the oobCode here>)
   .then(() => {
       // handle success here
   }).catch(err => {
       //handle failure here
   });
```

For React, I executed the above code in a useEffect hook (for when the page mounts). I can imagine there are similar types of features on Vue and Angular.

As correctly stated above, you can access the new emailVerified property using:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.reload().then(() => {
   console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified) // should now be 'true'
})
```